# Move 'p' into 'div' when clicked. - animation isn't working

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

This is just a demo of my real code, but the problem is the same. Is there any other or better solution to this. Why the animate() method isn't working....

```js
$('document').ready(function() {
  $('p').click(function() {
    var x = $('div').offset();
    $(this).animate({
      top: $(this).offset({
        top: x.top,
        left: x.left
      })
    }, 1000);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p style='position:relative;'>Move This</p>

<div style='height:100px;width:100px;border:1px solid black;margin-top:200px;'></div>
```

Comment: What is this construct? `top: $(this).offset({
        top: x.top,
        left: x.let
      })` - it is also misspelled even if it would work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`top: $(this).offset({ top: x.top, left: x.let })` is an incorrect construct and is also misspelled.

Here is the correction Including the clone. Note I had to make the div position absolute and change the p from relative to static after animation to insert the p into the div

```js
$('document').ready(function() {
  $('p').click(function() {
    var $p = $(this),
      $div = $('div'),
      $pc = $p.clone(),
      x = $div.offset();
    $pc.insertAfter($p).animate({
      top: x.top,
      left: x.left
    }, 1000,function() {
      $div.append($pc.css({"position":"static"}))
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.target {position:absolute; top:100px;height:100px;width:100px;border:1px solid black;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p style='position:relative;'>Move This</p>

<div class="target"></div>
```

Comment: @mplungjan......Thanks it's working perfectly. thanks again for paying attention on this......

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('document').ready(function() {
  $('p').click(function() {
    var x = $('div').offset();
    $(this).animate({
      top: x.top,
      left: x.left
    }, 1000);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p style='position:relative;'>Move This</p>

<div style='height:100px;width:100px;border:1px solid black;margin-top:200px;'></div>
```

Comment: ....Thanks a lot. Now it's working as expected.   "top: $(this).offset({"   was the problematic part. Can you help a bit more..... how can I make a copy of the text to move into the div not the real text???